# Cassandra is active (exited) after starting

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to get Cassandra to work on Linux Mint and I follow these instructions on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGhkX5z_vW8&list=PLalrWAGybpB-L1PGA-NfFu2uiWHEsdscD&index=4). They are the same like in the documentation:

JRE is openjdk version 1.8.0_242.

Cassandra is version 3.11.

My system is Linux Mint 19.3.

After starting Cassandra, I get this in my console:

[image]

There seems to be two problems, although I think if I fix one, I fix both:

(1) after "sudo service cassandra status" --> active (exited) should be active (running)

(2) after "nodetool status" --> Conncetion refused

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What's in your `system.log` usually in `/var/log/cassandra`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is actually nothing in my log. I have to admit after 20 years of Windows I changed recently to Linux Mint and sometimes I have some problems with installations etc. (I am quite new to programming as well). I tried both installations (and several reinstallations) according to the website (via tarball files and via Debian packages. I hope I did not mix up some stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, if this is a common problem or because of my ignorance. I could not make Cassandra work via Debian packages, but the INSTALLATION VIA BINARY TARBALL FILES worked fine on my machine. Here is the link to the official homepage:

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check listen_address and rpc_address whether it is default or server IP if not you have to update the IP address then try nodetool status with host. It should work.